# Break point not hit in just one file in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints, xcode7.3

I have an iOS app (with swift language) that started with xcode 7 and recently I updated to xcode 7.3.1.

Previously (before update xcode) everything was OK but recently when I tried to hit break point in specific function in one of the files, it doesn't get triggered.

I can trigger all break points in any other file but my problem is just this file.

Also I tried `(lldb) br list --v` and the result is:

```
Current breakpoints:
1: file = '/Users/daryasoft/Desktop/Imran/wonderwork/WonderWork/LinkParser.swift', line = 58, exact_match = 0
1.1: 
  module = /Users/daryasoft/Desktop/Imran/wonderwork/build/Debug-iphoneos/WonderWork.app/WonderWork
  compile unit = LinkParser.swift
  function = static WonderWork.LinkParser.Extract (Swift.String) -> Swift.String
  location = /Users/daryasoft/Desktop/Imran/wonderwork/WonderWork/LinkParser.swift:217
  address = 0x00069ad0
  resolved = true
  hit count = 0
```

And another interesting point is that I can't **step into** this function in debugging!

Comment: Try to remove or comment the line that breakpoint hit and see what happened.

Comment: @AliBaqbani I tried this and doesn't work for me